# Displaying Blender Execution Errors When Running From Subprocess

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python application in which I use the subprocess module to run Blender from the command line. Specifically, the Blender command executes a Python script that modifies an existing Blender file and then renders it. Currently, should an error occur inside the Blender script, utilizing the "--python-exit-code" argument inside my subprocess call ensures that Blender will close without rendering. What I would like to be able to do is isolate the traceback output and display it inside the console.

The reason I'm having issues with this task is because, it would appear, neither the standard output or standard error channels seem to carry the traceback text. When I run the exact same Blender command outside of subprocess and inside a regular console, the traceback text gets displayed. I've also tried using PySide's QProcess module and received the same results.

My main question is then, where does blender send this traceback text? Is is simply printed inside the main Blender script and not send to either channel, which may explain why it doesn't show up inside of subprocess or QProcess, but it does inside a regular console? In either case, what would be the best method to use in order to receive these traceback messages?

I should also mention that I have tried simply using try/except clauses inside the main Blender script, printing the error, and the using sys.exit(1) to manually exit the script. This seems a bit hacky however, and when I do use this method it leaves some memory unallocated upon program exit. So perhaps another side question would be, how does one properly exit blender from within a script? I will make a separate thread for this question should the answer to the main questions require this approach.

Thanks,
Peter